# Difference between Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) and Array.apply(null, arguments)

Tags: javascript, arrays

As far as I can tell, these two functions behave the same way:

```
function returnArgs() { return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) };

function returnArgs2() { return Array.apply(null, arguments) };
```

I see both approaches referenced all over SO, but still don't really understand why you'd use one over the other. Is it preference, or are there more practical forces at play? Perhaps I'm missing an obvious difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is pretty dangerous and won't always work. Try:

```
console.log(returnArgs2(3));
```

That'll show an empty array of length 3. The Array constructor interprets a single numeric argument as meaning you want an array of that length.

*edit* — as an update, based on [some interesting information about optimization](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers), if there's a "dangerous" thing here it's that "leaking" of the `arguments` object.  According to that article, passing `arguments` out of a function makes analysis of the function's code really hard, because the `arguments` object is so weird. If you want to prevent that, the safe thing to do is:

```
function returnArgs() {
  var rv = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
    rv.push(arguments[i]);
  return rv;
}
```

References to `arguments.length` are OK, as are references to properties of the `arguments` object that are integers corresponding with actual arguments. It's unfortunate that the "prettier" functional ways of doing this defeat the optimizer, but it's not really surprising.

The "weird" thing about the `arguments` object is that it provides aliases for actual arguments. For example:

```
function foo(a, b) {
  arguments[1] = a;
  return b;
}

alert(foo("hello", "world")); // "hello"
```

That assignment to `arguments[1]` has exactly the same effect as a direct assignment to the parameter variable `b`, and vice-versa. Thus if the `arguments` object "escapes" from a function, the static analysis code has no clue what may happen to the parameters (which are essentially the same as local variables), so it kind-of just gives up and leaves the function to be interpreted.

Note that that optimizer paper is about V8, but the problems of code analysis are not runtime-dependent. Nashorn, the new runtime in JDK 8, has a much different optimization approach, but I strongly suspect the net effect of misusing `arguments` are similar.

Comment: "dangerous" might be a little strong :)

Comment: Ok wow, yeah, so an array of length 1 will break it.  Good to know :)

Comment: @Pointy in order to solve that issue couldn't you do something like function `returnArgs2() { return arguments.length === 1 ? [arguments[0]] : Array.apply(null, arguments) };`

Comment: @DavidChase yes that'd work. I'm going to update this answer with stuff I've read more recently.